NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div' (used in the '_GamesComponent' component template)
I'm using Angular and when i'm using this code :
<div class="game-page-game-list">
            <div class="game-card" *ngFor="let game of AllGame">

i got this error :
NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div' (used in the '_GamesComponent' component template).
i tried to import CommonModule and Browsermodule in app.module.ts but nothing has changed

If you used GamesModule as Module you must Inject _GamesComponent
in the Feature Module GamesModule
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { YourComponent } from './Your.component'; // Replace with your actual component path

@NgModule({
  declarations: [YourComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [GamesComponent]
})
export class GamesModule { }


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
